# Fluid simulation giving an instant -x velocity

Tags: fluid-simulation

Here is my animation at frame 849 ( the frame before my fluid sim starts)

[image: bottlefluidintofunnel]

and here is my animation at frame 850 (the first frame of my fluid simulation)

[image]

After this, the fluid sim acts as expected but flows out of the random tube rather than the circle I have set as my inflow (which is the circle that is slightly visible at the opening of the bottle in the first image). My set velocity on my inflow is x: -.1, y: .1, and z: 0. Why is it creating this jut of fluid instantly? Additionally, I have the funnel set as the outflow (shell and volume), but the fluid only clips through it rather than disappears and I cant figure it out, is there something I am missing? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you post the link to your blender file?

Comment: Actually I did end up figuring it out, my normals were in the wrong direction on the inflow.